# Surnames that Codsworth supports

Tags: fallout-4

I was playing fallout 4. The first round I named my character 'John The Duvahkiin' (I just moved to Fallout from ES) and Codsworth called me 'Sir'. The second time I named my character 'Alex Johnson' and Codsworth called me 'Mr. Johnson'. I was wondering if there is any other surnames like this that when you choose Codsworth can call you by them.

Is there any other options like this in game? I didn't know about this and accidentally discovered it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [list of all names](https://www.pcgamer.com/au/does-fallout-4s-codsworth-know-your-name-check-this-list/) (Given names and Surnames)* that Codsworth recognises, without using additional mods.

They are, however not separated, merely ordered alphabetically. My bet is that names that are put in the "first name slot" and "last name slot" will determine whether or not he calls you "Adam", or "Mr/Mrs. Adams".

Additionally, I don't believe that there is a "middle name slot" that is recognised, and could potentially throw the whole thing out, resulting in Codsworth simply referring to you as "Sir" or "Ma'am", and [determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) like "the" would be a cause of this.

<sup>*NSFW Warning</sup>

Comment: This is probably the tamest "NSFW" warning I've ever seen...

Comment: Bad words are still NSFW. And let's be honest, I doubt you could pass off this list as "baby names" when your boss walks past. Lol

Comment: Additionally, it's also worthwhile remembering that the game has an MA15+ Rating (in Australia at the very least) and there are users on this site that are under that age. It's worthwhile following these rules, at least to uphold the reputation of the site

Comment: When I follow the link, I get a full-page popup ad of the main character from the Witcher series, I think, naked in a tub.  I think it's asking me to turn off my ad-blocker, but that's something I do for trusted useful sites, not sites that respond to me blocking ads by displaying content-covering ads =P